# Software for Interactive Analysis of Time Series Data

Tags: r

I use R and utilize the R-console to do so (from cran.r-project.org)

Seeking recommendations for a R language based software tool or R library that will help me to analyze time series data and zoom into sections of the plot graph.  Please let me know if you have any recommendation. The SW can be a commercial product.  Thank you for any information provided to this question.

The data is from a mechanical system. The data would be in a csv file and each line in the file would be in this generic format
<time stamp (micro second units), (integer numeric data fields) data 1,..,data n, (boolean data fields) 1..m>
The software should:

1. allow the csv data file to be selected, read and analyzed by a user provided R program
2. display any results of the analysis to a console window, allow it to be saved to a file, etc
3. plot the specified fields in the R-program as a time series
4. allow the user to interactively select a section of the plot using a mouse - this is a key requirement
5. plot only this section and display to console the analysis results specied in the R function, save the results, print plot to pdf/jpg etc
6. allow user to zoom back out to entire time series as in (3)

Comment: maybe you want to check whether ExPandDaR-package https://joachim-gassen.github.io/ExPanDaR/ meets your needs

Comment: you might consider `tsmp` package.

Comment: If you only need interactive plotting then `plotly` might be interesting. If you need to do various analyses frequently (or want other users to do it) you might want to look into writing your own `shiny`-App.
(See https://plotly.com/graphing-libraries/ and https://shiny.rstudio.com/).